# Use Visual Studio 2012 as Text Editor

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way of opening an in memory window within visual studio?

I'l like to use it like a text editor ( to modify XML data ), formatting, intellisense etc but I don't want to use File > New ... as this creates a physical file on my drive.

Comment: What you want is not clear.  It sounds like you want an editor that will alllow you to edit a document without having a file that exists.  Visual Studio does not support editing a file that has not been saved before.  The reasonf or this is because Visual Studio is not a text editor.  If you want that I would agree that Notepad++ is likely a better solution.

Comment: hmm why was my comment removed? I suggested notepad++ .

Comment: @Znau - I have no idea.  Based on the updated information the author wants an XML editor and Visual Studio is a horrible XML editor.

Comment: indeed. ah well, I'm getting used to have my comments removed with no explanation whatsoever.

Comment: It wasn't me that removed it. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio I don't believe so. You could take a look at [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It's a C#/VB.Net scratchpad to quickly write up code and test it out. There is a free version which is very nice. You have to purchase Pro to get intellisense.

Comment: LinqPad is excellent, i have already paid for pro. :) But i was hoping to use the editor to prettify some XML (amongst other things).

Comment: For XML I would recommend NotePad++ and some of the XML tools addons.

Comment: I'll have a look into this. Do you know if any of the plug-ins deal with xml that is not 100% well formed?

Comment: I use the XmlTools plugin (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#X) Not sure if it will address your case but it has a lot of options.

Comment: Just tried, these tools insist on perfect XML :( - Nevermind, slightly off topic. I'll continue the hunt.